# Cannot get <body> element to cover entire page

Tags: html, css

The objective here is for the sidebar to cover the entire height of the page. Right now #side does not have the height property set at all and it does span the entire body element as desired (when I had height set to 100% it did not span the entire body element... go figure). So it seems the problem is that #side's parent element, body, does not span the entire page.

I have tried (what feels like) a million different height options for both the HTML element and the body element, but nothing has worked. As seen in the picture below, this is as close as I've come to the body element spanning the entire height of the page.

A couple of things:

- I have a fixed background image that does cover the entire page. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the issue I'm having.
- The HTML element is the same size as the body element highlighted in the image below
- I have tried setting the min-height and height properties of body and HTML to 100% as well as 100vh and 120vh.
- Neither body nor HTML has any margins or padding.
- I have found similar questions posted but none of the solutions have fixed my problem.

[image]

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    /* I have also tried height: 100%; */
}

body {
    display: flex;
}

#side, #header-content {
    /* no specified height because I found it somehow made the divs shorter? */
    display: flex;
}
```

Body contains two divs, #side and #header-and-content. I'm not sure if the flexbox has anything to do with it... Additional CSS where I set the background image of the body element can be seen in the bottom right-hand corner of the attached image. Please let me know if there's any other relevant code I should post! Thanks! :)

EDIT: The HTML is across a couple of different files so here's a screenshot from the browser (yah I probably didn't need to censor my file paths but I'm on a server at work and I'm perpetually paranoid oh well)

[image]

Here's all the relevant CSS in a screenshot because I'm in a hurry:

[image]

UPDATE: the only thing that worked for me was commenting EVERYTHING out and adding elements and styling back in one by one... couldn't even tell you what the final issue was.

Comment: html, body should be height:100%, not min-height

Comment: It may be beneficial if you can share a little more of your related html and css code in the post, or create a link to your code with a jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) or similar tool.

Comment: @symlink I tried that and for some reason it makes no difference :/

Comment: @chris - The HTML is across multiple files so I figured a screenshot from the browser might be more useful?? I also included a screenshot of the relevant CSS.

Comment: Which browser have you tested this with? Is it just one browser that is misbehaving or is this a general problem? If it's browser-specific, that's probably a glitch in the code of said browser.

Comment: Have you tried to omit `display: flex` from `body`?

Comment: @A.Meshu - I did try that and still encountered the same issue :-) I think I will try another user's suggestion and just comment out everything and add things back one. at. a. time. :-))))))

Answer (score 3):

Style your the Body Element by setting its margin and padding properties values at 0, and set height property's value at 100vh.

```
body{
 height: 100vh;
 margin: 0; 
 padding 0;
}
```

Finally style your Body-Tag with a `height` of 100vh to set the size of the viewport in this way

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Don't apply the universal selector (*). Doing so will result in selecting other elements having the same property values as the body, and that will mess up your code entirely.

Comment: Yeah that definitely makes sense logically, but unfortunately it doesn't work for me.. it actually makes the height of the body element shorter than it is in the picture I attached. I tried with 100vh and 100%. Another post I saw also suggested html height 100% and body min-height 100% and that didn't work either. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is important to understand that elements other than the body tag can cause the entire body to appear off. In fact, usually it is an issue with another element that lies with-in the body. Remember all elements in the body are children of the body, they can and do affect the body element. First off do what was already suggested and set the body to what I consider to be the web standard for the CSS of a body tag.

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

If you are still experiencing an issue then you need to double check and make sure it is not the device/monitor you are using that is causing the issue. Load the page through a second device and see if you get the same result. If you don't have another device then use Mozilla's Dev-Edition Firefox Emulator to test the site. If you are still experiencing the issue I have found the top violator at this point to be borders. Borders pose the threat of throwing your pages body off a tad, because they wrap around the outside of an element. Here is an example to show you what I am trying to say:

- If you set a block div at 100% and wrap a border set at...

```
border: 1px solid #111;
```

around it, your div will actually equal (100% + 2px). This will cause the body to appear a couple pixels off. Depending on your browser, because different browsers deal with things differently, it could appear off on either the left or right. So check your borders, maybe try temporarily removing them. Next check margin. Margins are a major offender when it comes to issues like yours, they can cause a page to shift left or right, especially if the element is already at 100%-width. Lastly check any elements that widths are set at auto. Even if you don't set an elements width to auto many elements are set to auto by default. When an element automatically grows, it can potentially grow big enough to shift the screen a bit.

Lastly if you grow desperate, as a last resort you can remove every element and add them back to the page 1 by 1 until you find the culprit. If you are unable to solve it, I suggest taking this approach as it will help you learn the problem and gain a deeper understanding of the issue.
 - BEST OF LUCK --AFT3RL1F3

Answer (score 0):

Replace min-height with either of the following-

```
height: 100%;
height: 100vh;
```

Apart from this, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have added background image using CSS and `background-size` to cover the whole screen.I have created an example, hope it will help.

```css
body{ 
display: flex;
background: url("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1rfyCzcFPIQWylTF1nojkExMLvuogMmKU") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-content{ display:flex; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Nooo</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="header-content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </p>
    <p>It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
  
  </div>


</body>
</html>
```